# UI Automation, how to dynamically reference .staticText in progressBar?

Tags: ios-ui-automation

Here is the scenario for UIAutomation:

I'm uploading a file 'File A'. During upload there is a progress bar '0-100%' that reflects upload progress. This information is saved in .staticTexts & .value -- when I check logElementTree

```
UIATarget.localTarget().logElementTree();
```

a. I need to Reference & return .static text or .value of this element 
b. Assert against expected '100% completion'.

I'm defining realProgress to capture either static text or value of progress bar.
I've tried different iterations...  **What is the proper way of capturing current text percentages?**

```
    var realProgress = window.staticTexts()[0];
```

Output of my assertion function:

```
Expected 'Upload Progress 100%' but was '[object UIAStaticText]'!
target.frontMostApp().toolbar().buttons()["Icon Upload"].tap()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to add .name() at the end of my variable i'm asserting

```
     rProgress.name()

if (rProgress.name() != "your message"){
UIALogger.logerror("your error message not equal to " + rProgress.name() ) }
```